# LiveData Observer onChnaged Called Twice On Activity | Android

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata

I am using live date observer on activity. When I launch the activity first-time observer onChanged() called only once as usual. But when I press back and close the activity and then again launch the activity
observer onChanged() called twice. After that it is started triggering twice everytime I repeat these steps.

Here is the code of activity:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mLocLangQualViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(LocLangQualViewModel.class);
       mActivityLocLangQualSetupBinding = 
       DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_loc_lang_qual_setup);
       mActivityLocLangQualSetupBinding.rvLanguages.setAdapter(mSelectedLanguageAdapter);
       mActivityLocLangQualSetupBinding.rvLanguages.setLayoutManager(new 
       LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));

    mLocLangQualViewModel.getAllLangsofUser().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<LanguageModel>>() 
    {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ArrayList<LanguageModel> languageModels) {
                if (languageModels!=null){
                    Log.d("Observer","Called");
                   mSelectedLanguageAdapter = new SelectedLanguageAdapter(languageModels);
                   mActivityLocLangQualSetupBinding.rvLanguages.setAdapter(mSelectedLanguageAdapter);
                }

            }
        });
```

I have ensured getAllLangsofUser() function is called once..so only onchanged() of observer is called twice.

ViewModelCode:

```
public class LocLangQualViewModel extends ViewModel {

private LocLangQualSetupRepo  mLocLangQualSetupRepo= LocLangQualSetupRepo.getInstance();
private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LanguageModel>> langListLiveData;


public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<LanguageModel>> getAllLangsofUser(){
    Log.d("ViewModel","Method Called");
    if (langListLiveData==null){
        langListLiveData = mLocLangQualSetupRepo.getAllLangsOfUser();
    }
    return langListLiveData;
}
```

Comment: code looks alright. can you show the view model code as well.

Comment: yeah ..check now..i have updated

Comment: initially it will be null and when data is set again onChanged is called again.  What does the log say (Log.d("Observer","Called")) is seen twice?. you can just return  `mLocLangQualSetupRepo.getAllLangsOfUser()` in `getAllLangsofUser()`

Comment: yes...(Log.d("Observer","Called")) is shown twice